# How do I get a human readable date from a unix timestamp in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

In my javascript, I have a unix timestamp (in this instance `1318305600000") and I need to convert that into a human readable date via Javascript.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
// will display time in 21:00:00 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

For complete reference

```
getDate()   Returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
getDay()    Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
getFullYear()   Returns the year (four digits)
getHours()  Returns the hour (from 0-23)
getMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
getMinutes()    Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
getMonth()  Returns the month (from 0-11)
getSeconds()    Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
getTime()   Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970
getTimezoneOffset() Returns the time difference between GMT and local time, in minutes
getUTCDate()    Returns the day of the month, according to universal time (from 1-31)
getUTCDay() Returns the day of the week, according to universal time (from 0-6)
getUTCFullYear()    Returns the year, according to universal time (four digits)
getUTCHours()   Returns the hour, according to universal time (from 0-23)
getUTCMilliseconds()    Returns the milliseconds, according to universal time (from 0-999)
getUTCMinutes() Returns the minutes, according to universal time (from 0-59)
getUTCMonth()   Returns the month, according to universal time (from 0-11)
getUTCSeconds() Returns the seconds, according to universal time (from 0-59)
getYear()   Deprecated. Use the getFullYear() method instead
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Marking it as the answer as it gives a good reference for doing more than just giving the default date format

Answer (score 9):

```
alert(new Date(1318305600000))
```

Comment: Ok that works, but when I'm doing this in a variable (e.g. `new Date(x)`) I'm getting "Invalid Date".  When I output `x` to the chrome console it shows `"1318910400000.00"`.

Comment: That looks like a floating point number.  Try `parseInt(x, 10)` to truncate it to an integer.