# Converting Unix Date format

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization

I have a JSON that keeps DateTime values in unix view.

How do I convert it to human readable value using JavaScript?
For example:

```
1503575274000
```

to  `2017-08-24 15:11:54`

I am  using it to build charts using google visualization, my code looks like this:

```
function drawChart() {
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "jsonUrl",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: "false"
}).done(function (jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'dateExecutes');
    data.addColumn('number', 'passed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'failed');

    jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
        data.addRow([
            row.dateExecutes,
            row.passed,
            row.failed,
        ]);
    });
```

I also need to use regular date format instead of DateExecutes

Comment: `new Date(1503575274000)` should do it. That is not strange format, its called unix timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a human readable date from a unix timestamp in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827617/how-do-i-get-a-human-readable-date-from-a-unix-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: it's would be nicer to have your date like this : `2017-08-24T18:25:43.511Z` into your json, it will be automatically converted to javascript Date object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a UNIX timestamp. You just pass it to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) like so:

```
var d = new Date(1503575274000);
d.toISOString(); // "2017-08-24T11:47:54.000Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the unix timecode, as stated in the comments you can convert it like this:

```
new Date(1503575274000)
```

The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC. Therefore, the unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate Date/Time, I would recommend using Moment.js https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

```js
var dateTimeStr = moment(1503575274000).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

console.log(dateTimeStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```